# I'm trying to figure out how to add the values in an object using a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

Here's the code. I left the function block blank because I'm stumped

```
function getSummedAge(people) {
}
const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 10 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 25 }
];

console.log(getSummedAge(examplePeopleArray));
```

Comment: You will have to give us more information. What are you trying to achieve? what have you tried? etc

Comment: Also need to know which object in the array you want to update

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Which values you want to add in an object? Will be helpful if you can explain your problem in detail.

Comment: Sorry I realized I only copied the problem and not my attemp. I was trying to figure how I could add all the values in the age object. The output is supposed to be 55. I’m just leaning to code and was trying to figure out if I could use the object.values method to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the Array.reduce method! It's purpose is to basically *reduce* an array into a single value, which I believe is what you're trying to do here: [Array.reduce() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here's a little example of how you might use it in this context

```js
    function sumAllApplesIn(baskets){
        return baskets.reduce((accumulator, currentBasket) => accumulator + currentBasket.apples, 0)
    }

    const baskets = [
        { basket: "one", apples: 10},
        { basket: "two", apples: 15},
        { basket: "three", apples: 30}
    ];

    console.log(sumAllApplesIn(baskets));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop through the people array, grab the 'person' object, and then access the age key. Sum those up and voila

```js
function getSummedAge(people) {
    let summedAge = 0;
    for (let pdx = 0, plen = people.length; pdx < plen; pdx++) {
       let person = people[pdx];
       summedAge += person.age;
    } 
    return summedAge
}
const examplePeopleArray = [
    { name: 'John', age: 10 },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 25 }
];
    
console.log(getSummedAge(examplePeopleArray));
```